# Regex to remove initials from full name

Tags: java, regex, regex-negation

I have names like "D John Livingston" , "S. Jennifer Adstan" and I want only the initials to be removed from the names , "D" in the first name and "S." in the second name. How can i do it using java regex?

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: you should have to try something and give some result so that we can correct it even if its right.  :)

Comment: Easy way. Simple way. Search for String.split () method.

Comment: What about middle initials ("James T. Kirk")?

Comment: I tried this "(([A-Z]){2,})" which removes two consecutive uppercase letters if i use (([A-Z]){1,}) i get "ohn ivingston" as output.

Comment: https://www.regexpal.com/ is a really usefull resource for me personally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code snippet seems to be working well:

```
String input = "John O'Connel";
input = input.replaceAll("\\b[A-Z]+(?:\\.|\\s+|$)", "").trim();
System.out.println(input);

John O'Connel
```

Your question is chock full of edge cases, since an initial could be, for example, more than one letter, and could appear at the start, middle, or end of the name.  I replaced using the pattern `\s*[A-Z]+(?:\.|\b)`, which seems to at least cover your examples.  Also, I make a call to `String#trim()` for some whitespace cleanup for initials at the very beginning or end.

### Demo

Comment: "[A-Z]\\W+" is an alternative. Any uppercase letter followed by any amount of  punctuation or whitespace.

Comment: @BryanPatterson I think your suggestion would fail an initial occurring at the very end of the name, because in that case `\\W+` would not match.  Better to use word boundaries, which are zero width.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Good catch. Maybe "[A-Z]\\W*\\b"?

Comment: Also would your regex merge the first and last name if a middle initial was present?

Comment: Rather than commenting further, why don't you check the demo I included in my answer, which clearly shows this is not happening.

Comment: But for "John O'Connel" I get John Connel, It should be John O'Connel

Comment: @AshokKumar I updated my answer per your new requirements.

Answer (score 1):

For this I would consider using String [replaceAll()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

So how do we design the regex?

Basically there are three cases you need to consider:

- A. a single letter at the beginning of the name (optional period), followed by one
  space
- B. a single letter at the end of the name (optional period), preceded by one
  space
- C. a single letter in the middle of the name (optional period), surrounded by
  two spaces

For the first two cases, you need to leave no spaces. So you would match one space and replace it with zero spaces.

For the last case, you need to leave one space. However, rather than handling this case explicitly, you may treat it as either A or B, since those will replace only one of the two spaces, leaving you with the desired number of spaces: 1.

So how do we combine case A and case B together? Using the symbol of `|`.

To prevent grabbing a single letter from a larger chain of letters, you can use the word border marker `\b` on the side which is not demarcated by a space character. (Normally for cases A and B, I would have used `^` and `$` to explicitly match begin and end of string for this purpose. However, since we also need to handle case C in the middle of the string, we should use word border marker instead. )

And how do we represent the optional period? Since the period is a special character it must be escaped: `\.` Then it is marked as optional with question mark: `\.?`  However, there's still the problem that the  `A.` in the middle of a name might be matched as just  `A` since period also counts as a word border. To prevent this, we add a possessive quantifier to the optional period `\\.?+`.

Putting all of this together, our regex would be: `(\b[A-Z]\.?+ )|( [A-Z]\.?+\b)`
However, in the final Java string, the backslash must be escaped, so in the final Java string, each `\` will appear as `\\`

**Example code:**

```
String pattern = "(\\b[A-Z]\\.?+ )|( [A-Z]\\.?+\\b)";
String input1 = "MC Hammer I Smash U";
String input2 = "S. Jennifer A. Adstan JR.";
System.out.println(input1.replaceAll(pattern, ""));
System.out.println(input2.replaceAll(pattern, ""));
```

Output:

> MC Hammer Smash
>
> Jennifer Adstan JR.

Comment: Sometimes initials can be more than one letter.  Your pattern does not cover this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that was a deliberate choice on my part based on how I interpreted the question. Plus, they may want to hand-verify such cases to make sure they are not eliminating a two letter name.

Comment: Fair enough, but two _capital_ letters should not be mistaken for a name, I think.

Comment: @AshokKumar have a look at my latest edit. I have added the possessive qualifier and explained why it was needed.

Comment: @AshokKumar would love to hear why you unaccepted this answer. hi?